# Resizable EditText in Android ActionBar

Tags: java, android, layout, android-actionbar, android-edittext

I'm trying to build an element of my app that has a limited browser capability.

I have a layout consisting of an EditText field:

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/action_address_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:hint="@string/prefkey_homepage_default"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="textUri" >
</EditText>
```

This layout is plugged into an ActionBar menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_back"
    android:icon="@drawable/navigation_back"
    android:showAsAction="always" 
    android:title="@string/action_back"/>

 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_forward"
    android:icon="@drawable/navigation_forward"
    android:showAsAction="always" 
    android:title="@string/action_forward"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_address"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_stop" 
    android:actionLayout="@layout/action_address"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_stop"
    android:icon="@drawable/navigation_cancel"
    android:showAsAction="always" 
    android:title="@string/action_stop"/>
</menu>
```

This displays fine at present, but only in portrait.
When I rotate the screen, the portion of the window which is occupied by the menu doesn't resize.

What I would like to happen is that on rotate, the EditText resizes to fill the area, and the other buttons in the menu shift to accommodate it.

Obviously, I cannot give menu items a gravity/weight setting like I can with layout elements, so I'm a little stuck.

Ideally, because I'm still treading in the unknown with regard to Android, I'd like to avoid building an 'action bar' from scratch.

Can anyone advise on this?